# Trouble creating a ForeignKey relationship for my UserProfile immediately upon User registration

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to have a user registration form submit into two models (User and UserProfile) and immediately create the relationship where the UseProfile belongs to the User. I think the problem is about passing the request.user.id to the UserProfile model so that it knows who it belongs to.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    age = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    interests = models.TextField(default="")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def user_creation_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username', None)
        password = request.POST.get('password', None)
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
        user.save()
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        interests = request.POST.get('interests', None)
        age = request.POST.get('age', None)        
        pk = request.user.id
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(age=age, interests=interests, user=pk)
    return render(request, "profiles/user_creation_template.html")
```

user_creation_template.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>  
<form method="post" action="{% url "user_creation" %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Interests" name="interests">
    <input type="text" placeholder="age" name="age">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended approach to creating a UserProfile when creating a User is to use the [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#post-save) signal ([here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/) is the docs page explaining what they are).

What basically happens is that when a User model is created (saved for the first time) we create a UserProfile object linked to the User. Like so:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
```

NOTE: if you use a ForeignKey instead of a [OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) you're going to end up in a situation where an User has several UserProfiles (and thus you can't do `user.user_profile`).

The signal will be triggered when you do `user.save()`, so from there onwards you can just do (assuming you change the field to a OneToOneField):

```
user.user_profile.interests = interests
user.user_profile.age = age
user.user_profile.save()
```

to accomplish what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would begin by changing your relationship to a `OneToOneField`.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    age = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    interests = models.TextField(default="")
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

Next, I would make a `post_save` signal to generate the new profile.

```
django.db.models.signals import post_save

def new_user_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:         
        new_profile, is_created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(new_user_receiver, sender=User)
```